# MockServer unexpectedly responds with empty body

Tags: java, mockserver, mockserver-netty

Let's see a test, which is using MockServer (`org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:5.10.0`) for mocking responses.

It is expected that the response body will be equal to string `"something"`.
Nevertheless, this test fails, because the response body is an empty string.

```
  @Test 
  void test1() throws Exception {

    var server = ClientAndServer.startClientAndServer(9001);

    server
        .when(
            request().withMethod("POST").withPath("/checks/"),
            exactly(1)
        )
        .respond(
            response()
                .withBody("\"something\"")
                .withStatusCode(205)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        );

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                     .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:9001/checks/"))
                                     .POST(BodyPublishers.noBody())
                                     .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response =
        HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());

    assertEquals(205, response.statusCode());
    assertEquals("something", response.body()); // fails
  }
```

How to make the response body be equal to the string provided in `response().withBody(...)`?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `"something"` isn't valid JSON, as you claim with the Content-Type? In addition, should it be `"\"something\""` - though you say that the body is empty.

Comment: string is a valid JSON by definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the client side. It drops content.

Why!?

Because, `HTTP 205` is `RESET_CONTENT`.
This status was chosen accidentally for test as "somenthing different from HTTP 200", and unfortunately caused this behaviour.
Looks like it is very popular "accidental" mistake (i.e. [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/735)), although it is strictly in accordance with the [HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).